# How can I know the attribute that occurs more often from a list of Objects?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, count

I have a list of Passengers in an airport, each passenger has a destination, I want to know the destination that occurs more often.

The list is an ArrayList in java.

Comment: The answer is Paris. No, seriously, is this homework?

Comment: Its not homework, its for a project, but does it matter?

Comment: I tried using counters, but the problem is that the number of destinies is random, so it would not solve this..

Comment: Thanks for helping I manage using a map!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code optimized with only one for loop.

```
 package com.rais;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.rais.vo.Passenger;

/**
 * @author Rais.Alam
 * @date Dec 17, 2012
 */
public class Client
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Client client = new Client();

    Passenger p1 = new Passenger("A", "USA");
    Passenger p2 = new Passenger("B", "USA");
    Passenger p3 = new Passenger("C", "UK");
    Passenger p4 = new Passenger("D", "UK");
    Passenger p5 = new Passenger("E", "UK");
    Passenger p6 = new Passenger("F", "UK");

    List<Passenger> passengers = new ArrayList<Passenger>();
    passengers.add(p1);
    passengers.add(p2);
    passengers.add(p3);
    passengers.add(p4);
    passengers.add(p5);
    passengers.add(p6);

    System.out.println(client.getMostVistedDestination(passengers));

}

public String getMostVistedDestination(List<Passenger> passengers)
{

    Map<String, Integer> tempMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    int maxCount = 0;
    String dest = "";

    for (Passenger passenger : passengers)
    {
        int count = 1;
        if (tempMap.containsKey(passenger.getDestination()))
        {
            count = tempMap.get(passenger.getDestination()) + 1;
            if (maxCount < count)
            {
                maxCount = count;
                dest = passenger.getDestination();
            }

        }
        else if (maxCount == 0)
        {
            maxCount = count;
            dest = passenger.getDestination();

        }

        tempMap.put(passenger.getDestination(), count);

    }

    return dest;

}

}
```

Here is Passenger.java

```
package com.rais.vo;

/**
 * @author Rais.Alam
 * @date Dec 17, 2012
 */
public class Passenger
{
    private String name;
    private String destination;

    /**
     * @param name
     * @param destination
     */
    public Passenger(String name, String destination)
    {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.destination = destination;
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name
     *            the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the destination
     */
    public String getDestination()
    {
        return destination;
    }

    /**
     * @param destination
     *            the destination to set
     */
    public void setDestination(String destination)
    {
        this.destination = destination;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of (in pseudocode):

```
Map<Destination, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for(Passenger passenger : list) {
  Destination dest = passenger.getDestination();
  int times = 0;
  if(map.hasKey(dest)) {
    times = map.get(dest);
  }
  map.put(dest, ++times);
}
Collections.sort(map.values());
```